# The [rationale] for a meta-tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, meta-tags

So, [rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rationale) is a tag that exists. There are 36 questions on it.

So let's evaluate this tag:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   - Nope. There is pretty much nothing in common between those questions, other than the fact that they're all asking for the reason why something exists.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   - Well, yes, we do allow such questions.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   - Nope. All of those questions are pretty clear that they're about the reason why something exists.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   - Somewhat, yes.

One could argue that this is like the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag, in that they both describe the kind of answer you're seeking, rather than the content of the question. However, [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) has actually proven its worth, while [rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rationale) has not. People are clearly able to get answers to rationale questions without using the tag (unlike the language lawyer tag, without which comments and answers often don't explain what the language actually says).

So we don't need it. Furthermore, it's likely to be recreated if we simply remove the questions from it. So I think full burnination is appropriate.

Comment: Burninating seems open and shut, but I doubt it would get reopened. There aren't that many questions on it, and since most meta tags are gone, the incentive to open new ones is low. Blacklisting may be excessive (but if you think it isn't, add the blacklist-request tag to your question)

Comment: In [tag:ada], each major [version](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ada/3900/getting-started-with-ada/18706/version) has a [tag:rationale], in which an eminent [tag:language-lawyer], _inter alios_, elaborates on the interim changes.

Comment: Why do you think it's likely to be re-created? That doesn't seem like an obvious conclusion to me at all.